# Widgets Scripts don't load - but load when I reload the page

Tags: plugins, widgets, css, autoloading

I've recently made my website and added facebook web plugin script and instagram script on the widget bar. But when I go from the **Homepage to another Page it's not loading**. It's just loading when **I refresh** the site I currently am.

Someone knows how to solve this?

[image: my problem, it's not loading in the first place]

Comment: Hello and welcome to WPSE! In case your problem is caused by a problem, this site is not the right place to ask for help, check the plugin support forums in that case (Nevertheless have a look at [WPSE: What topics can I ask about here?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) Otherwise you should supply us with more information on what is happening, what you have tried etc. pp. See ["How to ask?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further information on that.